# Is it possible to save a video to the phone's camera roll on click? from website?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to save a video directly to the device camera roll with React.
Is it possible? I cannot seem to find too many info about this, only for React Native.

I am looking for a functionality similar to `<a href={videoLink} download>Save to camera roll</a>`

Answer (score 0):

There is a new [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) that you can try to use.

Other than this, you can't control where the file will be saved from a website.